# How to find number of records in a csv file placed in google cloud storage without downloading the file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have tried this but system tells 'wc' is not a valid command.

gsutil wc -l gs://folder/test.csv

please help me how to find no of records in a file without downloading it

Comment: There's no sign of a `wc` command in the docs so I guess it's telling you the truth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i have tried this and it is working

gsutil cat gs://folder/test.csv | wc -l

Comment: Great. You should be able to mark this as accepted. Note you are still effectively downloading the file and counting lines locally by streaming to stdout. @Doug's answer remains valid.

Comment: Narendran N@, if you are mainly trying to avoid the network cost/latency of downloading the file across the Internet, you could try running this command on a Google Compute Engine instance. That will still download the object, but the traffic will still in Google's network.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Storage doesn't provide any computing resources to deal with contents of an object.  The only things you can do are upload objects, download objects, or read/write metadata associated with an object.  There is operation to count lines or do anything else with the contents of an object.

Your choices are to either download the object and count the lines on the client, or count the lines **before** uploading the object, and attaching that to metadata so that it can be easily discovered without requiring a full download.